# ES Modules (.mjs) support in SonarQube

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonarqube

I can't seem to find this answer anywhere.
Does SonarQube currently support ES modules (`.mjs`) files?
This is a Node.js (v9.11.1) project.
As of now, I'm not sure if it's a configuration issue on my end, or if it's just lack of support, but it only recognizes and analyzes `.js` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `.mjs` to the list of file extensions. You can do that in the project (or global) settings:

[image]

You can also set this configuration via the "sonar.javascript.file.suffixes" key on the "sonar-project.properties" file. For example:  `sonar.javascript.file.suffixes=.js,.jsx,.vue,.mjs`

Comment: Thank you, sir! That works great. I've edited to answer to include the configuration file approach as well. Many thanks!